# Can a Familiar allow you to avoid verbal and somatic components?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, counterspelling

if I cast a spell and choose for it to come through my familiar, would I still have to do verbal and somatic components? what about material? would people be able to see the casting? could it still be counter spelled?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The final section of the *Find Familiar* spell says:

> Finally, when you Cast a Spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell. Your familiar must be within 100 feet of you, and it must use its Reaction to deliver the spell when you cast it. If the spell requires an Attack roll, you use your Attack modifier for the roll.

The only thing mentioned here is using the familiar to deliver the **touch** component of the spell, for which you use your attack modifier.

There is nothing in the spell description that alters any of the other aspects of casting a spell i.e. you still need the components or a focus, you have to make the somatic gestures and speak the verbal component.

You can still be seen casting the spell if you are in visual range and not hidden and if you are visible and in range then you can be *Counterspelled* as normal.

Comment: A variation on the original question: Could my familiar carry the material component instead of me?  I'd say it falls within the Rule of Fun, myself.

Comment: Obviously, the DM rules it is OK then it's OK but I personally wouldn't because that's getting suspiciously close to the familiar actually casting the spell which has ramifications.